# Angular 2 Routing ERROR in Cannot use "in" operator to search for "providers" in null

Tags: javascript, angular

I am testing the Lazy Router version with Angular.

I implemented for every component with the following parts:

```
in componentone.component.ts   
@Component({...})
export class ComponentOne ...

in componentone.module.ts
@NgModule({..., imports: [componentOneRoutes]})
export default class ComponentOneModule

in componentone.routes.ts
const routes = [ {path: '', component: ComponentOne} ]
export default RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

In my appcomponent.ts

```
@Component({})
export class AppComponent {
   // for displaying the content in url in the app.component.html
   navs = [ {url: '', content: 'Component 1'},... ]
}
```

In app.routes.ts

```
const routes = [ {path: "", loadChildren: 
"app/componentone/componentone.module"} ]

export default RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Then in app.module.ts import the app.routes.ts

```
@NgModule({imports:[appRoutes,...]})
```

I receive the following Error:
    ERROR in Cannot use "in" operator to search for "providers" in null.

My providers section is empty because i have no services only the routing part in the import array.

I am using angular 4 and angular-cli 1.0.0

Comment: do you know which part of code is emitting the error?

Comment: this is a strange error without code which causes the error

Answer (score 1):

The `loadChildren` syntax is not correct. It needs the name of the Angular module. Something like this:

```
 loadChildren: 'app/products/product.module#ProductModule'
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker that demonstrates the problem? Then we can more easily look at it further.

Comment: I have this issue too. It is weird in that once the app is running making a save in a routes file will make the problem go away. It seems like the first ng-build doesn't build correctly. Then a re-compile fixes it somehow. One thing I noticed is that the order that bundles and chunks are built in is different from the first build to subsequent builds. The subsequent builds have no error while the first one does

Comment: Love the PluralSight videos Deborah!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the above so it is crystal clear to everyone (as this is what worked for me):

**Change all your default exports, for example:**

1) In exporting class:

```
export default class GridModule { };
```

2) The class that imports the module:

```
import GridModule from './gridModule'
```

**Change these default exports to exports, for example:**

1) In exporting class:

```
export class GridModule { };
```

2) The class that imports the module:

```
import { GridModule } from './gridModule'
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this is described here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3826

First, remove the `default` annotation from your code (componens and others places).
Second, where are the definitions of `componentOneRoutes` and `appRoutes`?

Comment: I have already removed all the default annotation. appRoutes and component-one are posted above

Answer (score 0):

The below setup and files gives me the same error no matter what I change to match any of the solutions currently offered.

Current Setup

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.0
node: 6.9.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.3
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.1.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```

Account Module - To be lazy Loaded

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ACCOUNT_COMPONENTS } from './components/index';
import { ACCOUNT_CONTAINER } from './containers/index';
import { routes } from './account.routes';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
  routes,
  CommonModule,
],
exports: [
  ...ACCOUNT_CONTAINER,
  ...ACCOUNT_COMPONENTS
],
declarations: [
  ...ACCOUNT_CONTAINER,
  ...ACCOUNT_COMPONENTS
],
 providers: [],
})
export class AccountModule { }
```

Account Routing

```
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AccountComponent } from     './containers/account/account.component';

const accountRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: '',
    component: AccountComponent
  }
];

export const routes =  RouterModule.forChild(accountRoutes);
```

Main Routing File

```
import { AccountComponent } from   './account/containers/account/account.component';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'accounts',
        loadChildren: 'app/account/account.module#AccountModule',
      },
    ]
  },
  { path: '404-page', loadChildren: 'app/404-page/404-   page.module#PageNotFoundModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '404-page' }

];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

APP Module

```
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { RunbookEffects } from './core/effects/runbook.effects';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-    browser/animations';
import { routes } from './app.routes';


import { APP_SERVICES } from './core/services';
import { reducer } from './core/store/reducers';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { UserEffects } from './core/effects/user.effects';
import { AccountEffects } from './core/effects/account.effects';
import { ProjectEffects } from './core/effects/project.effects';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
   ],
  imports: [
    routes,
    MaterialModule,
    LayoutModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,

   StoreModule.provideStore(reducer),
   StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentOnlyWithExtension({
     maxAge: 5
   }),

    EffectsModule.run(UserEffects),
    EffectsModule.run(AccountEffects),
    EffectsModule.run(ProjectEffects),
    EffectsModule.run(RunbookEffects)
  ],
  providers: [
    Angular2TokenService,
    APP_SERVICES
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

})

Comment: can I see the definition of you AppModule?

Comment: Add pathMatch: 'full' in the redirect path

Comment: And you dont need to export the components in a lazy module

Comment: And could you open a new question for this?

Comment: Add appModule, added pathMatch and removed all the export of components out of modules.